# Export regional settings for later import

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, settings, unattended-processing

From [Add/remove keyboard languages through a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374851/4136325), I know I can change keyboard settings.

Is there also a way of exporting the current settings in the same format so that I can import it later?

I googled for "export control intl.cpl" and "intl.cpl parameters" to find possible parameters for the control panel

It is not sufficient to export a Registry key as [mentioned in one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542534/463115). I tried that, and it did not work. And it's obvious that this could never work: When you install a keyboard layout like Chinese simplified, Windows needs to install some required language features and download them. A Registry export/import will not do that.

[image: Screenshot of components to download]

Comment: Did you check `REG QUERY "HKCU\Keyboard Layout" /s` from your [quoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542534/463115)?

Comment: @jeb: I thought it was obvious that this cannot work. I tried it anyways and updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can export the next reg file and run in other computer:

Computer\HKCU\Control Panel\International

Comment: this could be a comment than a answer

Comment: That Registry key seems to contain language specific settings like currency symbols, time format etc. I'd like to change the keyboard only, not everything else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30001816)